# Angular repeat bind to independent objects

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a small Angular application which repeats a list of `project` objects and allows editing each individual object.

```
// app.html

<div ng-controller="ProjectsCtrl">

  <div ng-repeat="project in projects">
    <!-- EDIT -->
    <h3>{{ project.id }}</h3>
    <h3>{{ project.title }}</h3>
    ...
    <!-- END EDIT -->
    <p>
       <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="updateProject(project); showEditProject=true">Edit Project</button>
       <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="showEditProject=false">Cancel</button>
       ...
    </p>
    <div class="box row animate-show-hide" ng-show="showEditProject">
        <form name="editProjectForm" class="form-horizontal">
           <input ng-model="editProject.title" type="text" id="title" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" required /><br />
         ...
        </form>       
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


// app.js

projectsApp.controller('ProjectsCtrl', function ($scope, $http, ConcernService) {
    ...
    $scope.updateProject = function(obj) {
        ConcernService.list('projects/', obj).then(function(){
            $scope.editProject = obj;
        });
    };
```

This all works fine but as each object is passed on the `ng_click`*all* the `editProject` objects are bound to the same model. Is it possible to allow the form to open and each object is bound to each `project` independently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `updateProject` method in the parent scope is just assigning `project` to `editProject`.  You can just reference `poject` in the edit form.  There is no need for the `editProject` field.

```
// app.html

<div ng-controller="ProjectsCtrl">

  <div ng-repeat="project in projects">
    <p>
       <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="updateProject(project); showEditProject=true">Edit Project</button>
       <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="showEditProject=false">Cancel</button>
       ...
    </p>
    <div class="box row animate-show-hide" ng-show="showEditProject">
        <form name="editProjectForm" class="form-horizontal">
           <input ng-model="project.title" type="text" id="title" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" required /><br />
         ...
        </form>       
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


// app.js

projectsApp.controller('ProjectsCtrl', function ($scope, $http, ConcernService) {
    ...
    $scope.updateProject = function(obj) {
        ConcernService.list('projects/', obj).then(function(){
            $scope.editProject = obj;
        });
    };
```

Comment: Actually, this works great. The only problem is that I am displaying my projects details in another div (see edit). If I edit the details the project model in that div also changes and doesn't get reset when I  click 'cancel edit'.

Comment: If you want cancel to reset the value and maintain the binding with the additional div tags you will need to store a copy of the original value and re-assign the value back to project object if the edit is canceled. It would be easiest to accomplish this within the ng-repeat scope.

Answer (score 1):

Put the `updateProject` function in another controller and attach that controller to the div that has the `ng-repeat`. For example:

```
projectsApp.controller('ProjectCtrl', funciton($scope, $http, ConcernSerice) {
  $scope.updateProject = function(obj) {
        ConcernService.list('projects/', obj).then(function(){
            $scope.editProject = obj;
        });
    };
}
```

and then:

```
<div ng-repeat="project in projects" ng-controller="ProjectCtrl">
...
</div>
```

The `ng-repeat` creates a scope for each project. This will makes it so that when you do `$scope.editProject = obj;` this will be done on this scope rather than on the single parent scope created by your `ProjectsCtrl`.

**UPDATE:**

If you need to be able to reset any edits you made you will need to save a copy of your object. You can probably do this in your `updateProject`:

```
  $scope.updateProject = function(obj) {
        ConcernService.list('projects/', obj).then(function(){
            $scope.previousValue = angular.copy(obj);
            $scope.editProject = obj;
        });
    };
```

Then you would have to create a method for canceling that copies the values back:

```
 $scope.cancel = function(){
   $scope.showEditProject = false;
   angular.copy($scope.previousValue, $scope.editProject);
 };
```

Then call it from your template:

```
<button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
```

Comment: hmm. I see that this works but it is kind of useful to keep the two way binding to the obj so the displayed data also changes (see edit). But this needs to rest upon cancel.